# What's the health formula in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

How much health is gained per level up?

Does health per level increase retroactively after increasing endurance?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your character starts with a base HP of 80, with 5 extra points for every point of endurance.  When you level up you gain a base of 2.5 HP, along with half of your endurance.

**This effect is retroactive**, your HP will raise accordingly if your endurance increases.  Note that this does not account for any enhancements from gear, stims, or food.

In order to account for buffs, you can use the complete formula:

```
80 + (CurrentEndurance * 5) + (Level - 1) * (PermanentEndurance * .5 + 2.5)
```

`PermanentEndurance` refers to all endurance accrued via bobbleheads, the SPECIAL book, perk assignment, or initial SPECIAL assignment at the beginning of the game.  `CurrentEndurance` accounts for endurance bonuses from gear and buffs.

You can find more information in the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hit_Points) article.

Comment: Interesting, the formula is similar to Fallout Shelter.

Comment: The effect of permanent endurance is retroactive - if your endurance permanently increases (due to a bobblehead or perk assignment), you will retroactively be granted the HP.  I've updated my answer to be more complete.

Comment: @SkyHiRider but fallout shelter does not grant retroactive HP.

Comment: What is the difference between `CurrentEndurance` and `PermanentEndurance`, and why do they affect your HP differently?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft In short, `CurrentEndurance` accounts for temporary endurance gains.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.  Your HP is affected differently because that's how the formula was designed to work.

Comment: So endurance earned from perks gives more HP than endurance earned from buff-food?  That seems unlikely, do you have a source _(what the wiki says is ambiguous, and could be interpreted in several different ways)_? Have you actually tested this _(eg. according to this, a +1 endurance buff will always give you +5 HP, regardless of your level)_?

Comment: I tested this when I first wrote the answer, with a base endurance of 4.  My results supported the formula - I used a +END armor, mirelurk queen steak, and buffout for testing.  Note that the wiki *has* been updated since I posted the answer (old version [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hit_Points#Fallout_4)).  I will find some time to test the formula in the current wiki article.

Comment: Endurance from **armor** doesn't increase health, but endurance from **clothing** will.  So the +END hats are the only equipment that can give you more HP in the base game.

Answer (score 3):

For notation that is easier on the eyes: **Health** = 80 + (END * 5) + [(2.5 + (END/2)) * (Level-1)] + Perks

I have been doing some min/max testing on health and it seems you gain the initial endurance boost from character creation AND the theoretically retroactive boost that you missed from all previous levels upon putting points into endurance. I tested the formula for a level 30 character that has a current value of 11 endurance who started out with 2 endurance, AND my other level 50 character who has 10 endurance and started out with 9 and that formula is correct for both. This means that your hp value is based upon whatever your current endurance is(Not Retroactive). Hope this detail could clear things up for other theorycrafters and min/maxer's out there.

Comment: The formula you've given makes no distinction between permanent and temporary endurance - you should make some distinction between the two, as it does effect the outcome of the formula.

Comment: I've found that having bonus endurance over my base endurance of 11 does not affect total health, so really there is no distinction to be made in my situation at least. Perhaps it accounts for characters that have <10 endurance as there seems to be a cap on "CurrentEndurance" health bonuses.