# What stats are affected by leveling up?

Tags: fallout-4

> **Related:** [What's the health formula in Fallout 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242578/whats-the-health-formula-in-fallout-4)

A friend asked me if there were any relatively easy ways to permanently boost your SPECIAL stats or other character attributes. I replied that there are some things like bobble-heads and magazines, but those are relatively rare. So, the most reliable source of permanent stat boosts is by choosing a SPECIAL stat or perk on level-up.

However, answers to the related question linked above seem to indicate that there is some passive effect on stats based on your level alone. This still means most of your stat boosts are going to be XP-based, but it also means that the stats aren't *only* tied to player choice or skill points.

So, I'm looking for more specifics here. How does each character level affect your character's attributes? The most obvious stats, which I'd like to see answered for as a minimum, are listed below. If there's others known to be affected, please do include them.

- SPECIAL Stats

  - Strength
  - Perception
  - Endurance
  - Charisma
  - Intelligence
  - Agility
  - Luck
- Derived Stats

  - Action Points
  - Carry Weight
  - Damage Resistance
  - Energy Resistance
  - Radiation Resistance
  - Maximum Hit Points
  - Melee Damage
  - XP Modifier

Are there any of these (or any others I haven't thought of) that get a boost just by gaining a character level, even if a skill point isn't spent on a related SPECIAL stat or Perk? If so, how much per level?

Comment: Im quite sure that it does not effect anything in S.P.E.C.I.A.L. other then giving you the ability to asd a point via a perk. However, I think the scope of your question (which is effectivley a list) makes this too broad. Perhaps it woukd be better to ask if levelling effects anything other then immediate perks and hitpoints, first.

Comment: @Timelord64 The primary scope here is well-defined. The list of stats in question is over a dozen long, but still very finite. Though I can't say for certain, it's probably even exhaustive of all the stats which *might* be affected by level-up. SPECIAL stats don't appear to be visibly affected, unless the player actually spends a point on them. But that doesn't mean there isn't some background boost happening during level-up. Also, some amount of change to derived stats would be roughly equivalent to a change in their associated SPECIAL stats except that they wouldn't actually unlock Perks.

Comment: You are asking about non-displayed stats in this case. I wish you luck in getting an answer though. I went off and checked a couple of displayed values to see if they were affected by character level then gave up... Maybe someone else can go summarize the wiki for you :)

Comment: @James I just checked the wiki (well, one of them) and it looks like Max HP is the only value documented to be affected by player level. However, I've also observed the wikis for this game to be far from comprehensive at this time - understandable, given how young the game is. So, I'm hoping someone with enough interest and a copy on the PC (I'm on XB1) might poke around the console and figure it all out for certain.

Answer (score 5):

Based on playing the game one and a half times, it appears that **the only player stat that automatically increases when you level is your health**. I've certainly not observed any of the other stats you listed increasing due to level.

If someone runs across something else, please drop a comment.